# How to hide empty element?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below in WordPress. How can I make the word "Detail" disappear in frontend if there is no content?

```
 $detail = get_term_meta( $tagid, 'detail', true );
     <div class="mt15 fontbold font120">Details:
     </div>
     <div class="detail-div">
           <?php echo do_shortcode($detail);?>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if detail is empty. When yes, put out an empty string, else "Details:";

```php
$detail = get_term_meta( $tagid, 'detail', true );

<div class="mt15 fontbold font120"><?php echo empty(do_shortcode($detail)) ? '' : 'Details:'; ?>
</div>
<div class="detail-div">
    <?php echo do_shortcode($detail);?>
</div>
```